# Is there any way to run multiple detection models (with tracking) at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, socket.io, object-detection

I'm taking socket stream from android app and sending it to server where we need to take each frame and run 4 object detection models. And to run all four models at the same time I'm using threads Library of python. Problem is that when we call one thread (i.e one model) it takes 1sec for 1 iteration but when I call 4 threads it should take 1sec because of parallel processing but it is taking around 3sec.
Can anyone help me with this whether I'm using threads in a wrong way r is their any way to check whether parallel is happening or not or any alternate for this work

Answer (score 0):

Threading doesn't really means parallel processing if you want to run models parallely use multi processing instead of multi threading. If your 1st thread has started running at 1.00s then other thread might start at 1.001s and not 1.00s. If you want to start processes together at 1.00s use multi processing.